# Iphone Lightning Charger - How would one go about it?

Tags: charger

[image]

Hello, im completely new to EE, but im doing my best to learn. For a starter, i want to make a device that can charge an iphone with a battery pack. Ive read up a little, and i think this would work, for the power itself, im not sure however. Can anyone try to explain why it would, or would not work, and/or how i would go about making such a device. I hope this question isnt to wide, but i could try to narrow it down a little if needed.

EDIT: I noticed the R1 component should actually be on 6 Ohms, so pretend its there. Thank you :)

Comment: The voltage drop across a resistor is dependent upon the current being drawn, and the initial plug-in to the phone will be in excess of 6v which may permanently ruin it.  There are specialized charging ICs which are dirt-cheap and designed exactly for this.

Comment: @insta Thanks for advice! On the other hand, could some sort of capacitator setup solve this? As it would stop the current for a while?

Comment: Short answer: no.  You really need active voltage regulation -- the simplest is a linear regulator, most complicated is a switching regulator, and middle of the road is a purpose-built chip for that.

Comment: @Insta if you care to post an answer, ill accept it as soon as possible. Thought you might as well, as you acctualy answered it.

Comment: If you want an equally simple solution, replace the resistor with a diode, that will give you a much more consistent voltage drop and bring the voltage down closer to 5.3V (N.B. some Alkaline cells are closer to 1.6-something volts when new). But as mentioned in the answers below, a proper regulator is best (although you might want to make sure it's a Low Drop Out regulator or LDO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach has numerous problems -- there's no active voltage regulation as a primary point.  Resistors do not drop a fixed voltage, rather it's dependent upon the current flowing through them.  In some instances you will have a much higher voltage than the phone will likely tolerate, which may cause permanent damage.

Your options are:

1. A linear regulator.  Linear regulators take a higher input voltage, and burn the difference between the input and output voltage off as heat.  They provide extremely clean and stable outputs, but are extremely inefficient and require upwards of 2 volts higher than the output to remain stable.  A mechanical equivalent is dragging a brake on a motor to keep its speed regulated.

[image: linear regulator]

2. A switching regulator.  Switching regulators use inductors as "flywheels" to transform voltages at high efficiency.  A mechanical example here is to strike a heavy spinning flywheel with a fast, lightweight hammer whenever its speed drops.  The "ping" of the hammer adds a bit of energy back to the flywheel, which keeps its speed in the right area.  These circuits "ping" the inductor several thousand to several millions of times per second.  The transfer of energy here is very efficient.

[image: Switching regulator graphic]

There are premade switchmode modules all over eBay for pennies.  I'd highly suggest repurposing an existing device to suit your needs, since that will satisfy about 30% of EE anyway.